# What terminology should be used to refer to a Local API in a world of REST APIs?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api

I am trying to create an API documentation website for a Local C# API. By local, I mean that it is not a web-based REST or SOAP API and relies on a referenced library within the user’s .NET Framework or .NET Core project to access. I would like to create web-based documentation for the API similar to this site ([Revit API Docs](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/b22df8f6-3fa3-e177-ffa5-ba6c639fb3dc.htm)) but I think I’m missing some major terminology here because I know some sort of documentation auto-generation tools must exist for my API type, but I can only seem to find them for REST and SOAP APIs when I search the internet. How should I be referring to a ‘Local C# API’ when searching the internet for docs auto-generation tools? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!!!

Comment: Are you talking about documentation tools that take your [XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) and turn then in to documentation for use with tools like [ghostdoc](https://submain.com/ghostdoc/), [VSDocMan](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html), [doxygen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/)? For example, VSDocMan can take your XML comments, turn them in to CHM files or even websites that [look like MSDN](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/samples/HTML/topic_000000000000003B.html).

Comment: @Andy Yes, exactly! But, I would actually see more personal benefit from auto-generating the structure/outline of my API and I planned to use it less for reading from the code comments. Can VSDocMan generate a webpage w/ html, css and linked webpages?

Comment: Yes -- they have a 14 day free trial.. Give it a shot. I personally use it for all my nuget packages.